# Is a certain sumset derived from primes of a certain form the set of all naturals?

Tags: nt.number-theory, prime-numbers, sequences-and-series, goldbach-type-problems

OEIS [A167055](http://oeis.org/A167055) Numbers n such that $12n + 5$ is prime.

$0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 7, 8, 9, 11, 12, 14, 16, 19, 21,...$ are items of  OEIS $A167055$.
I conjecture that the set of the sum of every two items of this sequence is the set of nonnegative integers. i.e.:$0+0=0,\ 0+1=1,\ ...,\ 1+4=5,...$

Further information for $A167055$ not in OEIS
$A167055$: nonnegative integers  that not of the following two forms:
$$
\begin{align*} 
&3x^2+(6y−3)x−y\\ 
&3x^2+(6y−3)x+(y−1) ,\ x,y \in \mathbb{Z^+}
\end{align*}
$$

Is there some clue to solve this problem?

More information see: [How come if  i  not of the following form, then 12i+5 must be prime?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/775648/how-come-if-i-not-of-the-following-form-then-12i-5-must-be-prime)

Comment: Also see: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/799731/conjecture-on-oeis-a167055

Comment: Thanks for the edit and understanding.Hiden information for this question: $0+0=0$ means $12*0 + 10 = 12*0 + 5 + 12*0 + 5$

Comment: This is somewhat stronger than Goldbach's conjecture for even numbers of the form $12n+10$.

Comment: @LevBorisov indeed there are variants of Golbach problem in the literature that correpsong exactly to this in the literaure, see my answer for some details.

Comment: This is not the answer,for reference only.At last the question becomes this: Let $A=\{n\ |\ 2n+1 \in \mathbb{P}\}$, let $B$ be the set of the sum of every two items of $A$,then $B=\{n \in \mathbb{Z}\ |\ n>1\}$.This is equivalent to every even integer greater than 4 can be expressed as the sum of two primes.

Answer (score 7):

Let us denote the set of all the $n$ such that $12n+5$ is prime by $P$. The number of $n\le N$ in $P$ is about $3 N / \log N$. It is conceiveable that the sum of pairwise sums of a set that dense are all positive integers, but to show that should be very hard.

One might compare the problem with the Golbach problem. There one has a set of density $N / \log N$, the primes, and expects to find all even numbers as sums of two (the odd ones being trivially impossible).

So, the problem at hand is about the same, on the one hand slightly easier as the set is a bit denser $3 N / \log N$ vs $N / \log N$ or rather $2 N / \log N$ (the density among the odd numbers) but then on the other hand  harder as the set might be a bit less direct to approach than the primes.

Actually problems like this got studied quite a bit, though set up slightly differently at least the presentations I know (see for example [K. Halupczok, On the ternary  Goldbach problem with primes in arithmetic progressions having a common modulus](http://wwwmath.uni-muenster.de/u/karin.halupczok/Publik/JA07endversion.pdf) for a recent paper). Namely one asks the "Golbach questions" for primes restricted to those in some arithmetic progressions with the same modulus. So in that language your question would be if all numbers congruent $10$ modulo $12$ are the sum of two primes congruent $5$ modulo $12$. This is too hard  to solve at present, as is binary Golbach.

However, if you change your question to asking for sums of three number of that form then it is known at least all sufficiently large numbers are of that form (paralleling asymptotic ternary Goldbach); this follows from a result of J. Zulauf [Beweis einer Erweiterung des Satzes von Goldbach-Vinogradov.
Journal für die reine und angewandte Mathematik, 1952](http://resolver.sub.uni-goettingen.de/purl?GDZPPN002176513).